How to Display Zip Code Labels in Power BI Shape Map
I am working on Power BI dashboard which displays a shape map based on US Zip Codes. I am able to get the Zip Code shapes displayed correctly on the map. When I mouse-over I can show tool-tips with zip code and additional information. However, I would like to show Zip Code Labels on the map without having to mouse-over.
My question is how can I show Zip Code Labels inside each shape similar to this example below? Thank you!

